# Two Switches to Separate Lights and One Constant Hot Outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I ran into an issue while trying to rewire my bathroom's electrical system. I have a small diagram below to illustrate my intentions:
[image]

Basically I have two switches, Switch A) is for the hall light, and Switch B)for the bathroom. Alongside the bathroom switch is GFCI outlet that I'd like to keep constant hot. There are two Sheaths of wire cover that come from the ceiling in between the sheetrock. One of them has three wires (white,black,red), and the other is just two wires (white,black). My question is how do I wire this up to work as mentioned? I have spent several hours on it and no luck.

Comment: Can you post photos of the switch box(es) and both light boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up playing with the wiring for a couple more hours and this is what I needed:

[image: Wiring of 2 switches to two lights and one constant hot outlet]

To be clear, I just wanted two switches that controlled two separate lights, and off of those wires I wanted to create an outlet/receptacle that was always on, regardless of switches. The diagram above accomplishes this.

Comment: The diamond shapes in the image above are wire nuts, correct? And you ran pigtails at these locations? Also, the bathroom switch on the right above has just the red wire going to its upper terminal, correct? Lastly, for the hallway light switch I see you're showing 3 terminals. Did you use a 3 way switch or a single?